# Correct way to implement timed home widgets? (pre Honeycomb)

Tags: android, timer, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I'm asking about home widgets like for Google Play or Youtube. They loop repeatedly through 5-10 items, going to the next one like each 5 seconds.

I read that this can be done with alarm manager, but in all posts about that, people say, that a high update rate will consume much battery life. [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287796/android-widget-update-after-x-time) there's somebody talking about using timer with Handler. But is this a valid approach in a BroadcastReceiver?

Do I have to "wake up" the broadcast receiver each time to loop through the items, with alarm manager? Or how is this done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to their app widgets on Android 3.0+? If so, they are probably using `AdapterViewFlipper`.

Comment: No, I'm seeing them in a device with 2.3

Comment: Do you then see the behavior when using a third-party home screen (i.e., not the one that shipped with the device or ROM)? It may be that these "app widgets" are really features of the default home screen implementation on that device. If you see it on a third-party home screen, it's definitely an app widget.

Comment: I don't know how to use a third party home screen, but I tested in 3 devices - Galaxy S, Galaxy ACE and HTC desire. All 2.3. I also tested an analog clock widget in the emulator (this should update each minute).

Comment: So these widgets can do this because they are shipped with the device? :/ No way to do it with a normal app, pre honeycomb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this post there's somebody talking about using timer with Handler. But is this a valid approach in a BroadcastReceiver?

Not really, because it will only work so long as your process exists, which is probably not going to be very long.

> I don't know how to use a third party home screen

Download one from the Play Store, install it, press HOME, and choose the newly-installed home screen.

> So these widgets can do this because they are shipped with the device?

That is not what I wrote.

A home screen is a program, written by a programmer. It can do whatever that programmer chose to have it do.

App widgets involve inter-process communication for every update, which is why they are a bit expensive if you update a lot. A home screen does not need to use inter-process communication to update *itself*. Hence, some manufacturer-supplied fancy "app widgets" are not implemented via `AppWidgetProvider`, but rather are features of the home screen app itself, simply listed and configured as if they were app widgets.

> They loop repeatedly through 5-10 items, going to the next one like each 5 seconds.

On Android 3.0+, the best answer is to use `AdapterViewFlipper`, as you do not need to manually update it -- the `AdapterViewFlipper` will pull the next bit of content as dictated by the configured update period..

On earlier versions of Android, you will need to do this yourself, and `AlarmManager` is probably the most reliable option if it truly has to be time-based updating. Please consider letting the user control the update frequency, including disabling the time-based updates entirely.