# listview in app widget android

Tags: android, listview, android-appwidget

hi friends [enter link description here](https://github.com/alchemisthq/appwidget-listview)

this link to create list view widget for my app, but here i want to add a button below the list view ,which on click will open my app,
using the below code to acheive this,because it worked for me on other app, but not with  this example, how to do that .

class widgetprovider

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    // String to be sent on Broadcast as soon as Data is Fetched
    // should be included on WidgetProvider manifest intent action
    // to be recognized by this WidgetProvider to receive broadcast
    public static final String DATA_FETCHED = "com.wordpress.laaptu.DATA_FETCHED";


    /*
     * this method is called every 30 mins as specified on widgetinfo.xml this
     * method is also called on every phone reboot from this method nothing is
     * updated right now but instead RetmoteFetchService class is called this
     * service will fetch data,and send broadcast to WidgetProvider this
     * broadcast will be received by WidgetProvider onReceive which in turn
     * updates the widget
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // which layout to show on widget
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        Intent informationIntent = new Intent(context,info.class);
        PendingIntent infoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, informationIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnSeeMore,infoPendingIntent);

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RemoteFetchService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
```

manifest added a activity

```
<activity android:name=".info" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

when on click it should open my app,how to do that please help, thank you

finaly i solved what i want to get,
just wrote a button click code onReceive & it worked

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(DATA_FETCHED)) {
            Log.i("inside action", "DATA_FETCHED");
            int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(context);
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetId);

              Intent informationIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
              PendingIntent infoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, informationIntent, 0);
              remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.txtSeeMore,infoPendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define how the PendingIntent you are setting will be handled, by overriding the onReceive method inside your provider :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_NAME)) {
        // Open your activity here.
    }
}
```

If every item in your ListView needs a different extra to help the onReceive create the proper Intent, you can use a FillInIntent for each item of the ListView, in getViewAt :

```
// Set the onClickFillInIntent
final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt(YourWidgetProvider.ACTION_EXTRA_ITEM, event.getId()); // retrieve this in onReceive with intent.getIntExtra(ACTION_EXTRA_ITEM, -1)
fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.listview_main_layout, fillInIntent);
return rv;
```

Also, don't forget to add your Provider and your RemoteViewsService to your Manifest :

```
<receiver 
    android:name="com.example.YourWidgetProvider"
    android:label="@string/widget_name">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
         android:resource="@xml/provider_definition_in_xml" />
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.example.YourRemoteViewsService"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
     android:exported="false" />
```

**EDIT :**

To handle clicks on buttons in the main widget (not in the collection view), it's even easier :

```
rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_id, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                        new Intent(context, YourWidgetProvider.class)
                        .setAction(ACTION_NAME),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

The ACTION_NAME needs to be different from the name you use for the clicks on the collection view, of course, since it needs to produce a different Intent.

I hope this helps !

Comment: You can check http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html or http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html#.UqWUA2TuLnR if you need examples of complete implementations ;)

Comment: please will you suggest me how to get this withn the above mentioned link, because the method you suggested i tried that in other example, that worked there but not with the link,

Comment: let me clear you ,i have 1 button on my widget ,which on click sholud open my app ,& not on the listview row click

Comment: see my edited answer. Instead of your Service as the class to be used for the intent, you just set your Provider.

Comment: i tried ,12-09 16:01:48.060: I/InputReader(472): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.37788 ]
12-09 16:01:48.060: I/InputDispatcher(472): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
12-09 16:01:48.060: I/InputDispatcher(472): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
12-09 16:01:48.080: I/InputDispatcher(472): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
12-09 16:01:48.080: I/InputDispatcher(472): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
12-09 16:01:48.170: I/TwDVFSBroadcastReceiver(770): onLauncherIntent

Comment: thanx @2Dee 4 your help,u guided wll thanx

Comment: With pleasure ! Please accept the answer to close the question if you have no further doubts regarding this. Thank you ;)

Comment: ya i have 1 more doubt ,since its a widget i want the list sholud update every after 5 min, after 5 mins it sholud fetch data from provided link..,you have any idea

Comment: That is an entirely different question :) There are many answers to it, for example this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287796/android-widget-update-after-x-time